# Is this a valid method for finding the integral of a polynomial through finite differences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Suppose the sequence of $x^2$ and the sequence of its differences up to the second, and the sequence of $x^3$ and its differences up to the third.

```
                                                0    1    8    27    64
        0  1  4   9  16                            1    7    19    37
         1  3   5   7                                6    12    18
          2!  2!  2!                                   3!    3!
```

Note that if we multiply the constant row of cubic differences by $\frac{2!}{3!}=\frac13$, we transform it into a row of $2!$. However, $\frac13 x^3$ is the integral of $x^2$. This seems to work for every polynomial $x^n$, that is $\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}$, giving the integral $\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}$. I can't seem to prove this beyond intuition, and I'm not exactly why this works. Any insight would  be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking why the $n$-th order difference of the sequence $\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $n!$ ?

Comment: No, I proved that informally and separately so in this case I'm taking it as a given that nth difference is n!  . I'm wondering what the reason is multiplying the bottom row by n! over (n+1)! would happen to give the integral of the x^n polynomial.